# Input with name, value and text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to have multiple `<input type="submit" ... />`

that addionaly are sending some value

`<input type="submit" name="test" value="1" class="btn btn-success" />`

`<input type="submit" name="test" value="2" class="btn btn-success" />`

`name` is used as a `binding variable` name and `value` as `value`

but `value` is also used as a `text`

How can I put there different text?

something like

`name="test" value="2" text="two (2)"`

Comment: You should use for example <input type="text"... or <input type="hidden"... to post data with the form, not the submit-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use input with type **hidden** if you don't want the user interacting with the value:

```
<input type="hidden" value="2" />
```

Of course, be sure to validate the input on the server side, it's really easy to post values there other than you have put in.

Comment: Hey, I misunderstood and this probably isnt going to work that way. I want to submit additional data dependent on which submit button user clicked, but with two hidden inputs both would be sent. Chris Pratt's answer works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `button` element, which is the most correct approach anyways. Using `<input type="submit">` is an anti-pattern.

```
<button type="submit" name="test" value="2">two (2)</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for what I wanted to achieve